# Linking into a page with a hash fragment (so user lands at specific content on page) issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

**The Feature I Want:**

I want to give a user a link like `mysite.com/foo#bar` so when they hit this link they land on the page foo and are scrolled half way down the page to the content with the id `bar`. It should be noted that this link will always be clicked from off site or typed into the address bar manually, the user will not already be on the page with all assets loaded.

Also fyi I am using angular and the page in question each bit of content is in an element directive, and in each directive template there are images

**The Issue:**

Easy enough right? Well I'm running into some problems, most of the time it works, but maybe 40% of the time it doesn't and the user lands above the content, I believe this is because the browser scrolls to the correct point on the page, but then slightly afterward images are loaded in above it pushing the rest of the page down, leaving the user in a random unintuitive spot. (For some reason the failure rate seems to be worse on iPhones...)

**What I've Tried So Far:**

In a run function I look for a hash fragment on any route and scroll to it if it exists.

```
    if($location.hash()) {
        $anchorScroll();
    }
```

I've tried:

- Wrapping it in a timeout

This works sometimes but is obviously not consistent, sure I can set it to 500ms and on a great wifi connection it's fine, but not on a mobile with poor signal

- listening for $viewContentLoaded

Too fast, ui-router seems to fire this event way before the page is rendered

- Emitting an event in each post-link function for all directives on the page.

  ```
  link: function ($scope) {
      $scope.$emit('loadingFinished');
  ```

Then picking that up again in the run function

```
$scope.$on('loadingFinished', function () {
    $timeout(doAnchorScroll, 500);
}
```

This raised the success rate but still wasn't foolproof. And I witnessed it leaving the user stranded in weird spots mainly on iPhones.

Can anyone suggest a way of detecting a moment where it is safe to scroll, or perhaps some other way of ensuring landing in the correct spot?

Answer (score 0):

Two things - first is a user-scroll should prevent it - you don't want to be scrolling the view if they've already scrolled. Second is listening for the images to finish loading.

Listening for the images is quite easy:

```
$("img").one("load", $anchorScroll);
```

Then in $anchorScroll I'd suggest checking if all images have loaded, and returning immediately if not (bonus points if you only check images above the anchor - but only doing a quick reply):

```
var scrolled = false;

function $anchorScroll() {
    var allLoaded = true;

    $("img").each(function() {
        if (!this.loaded) {
            return allLoaded = false;
        }
    });
    if (scrolled || !allLoaded) {
        return;
    }
    ...
```

The scrolling is possibly slightly harder - you can check for scroll events, but they are slightly different between platforms - and might even get fired for the manual scroll - if you find that happens then simply have a global that says "I'm scrolling here" and ignore it, otherwise:

```
$(document).one("scroll", function() { // Use ".on" if this gets fired for code...
    scrolled = true;
});
```

Note that you probably don't need to care about failed image loads, or ones that have already loaded, since your initial call to `$anchorScroll()` will catch them.